# Why are isometries of Minkowski space necessarily linear?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, special-relativity

The Mazur-Ulam theorem says that any surjective isometry of normed vector spaces is affine. This argument doesn't seem to apply to Minkowski space (of special relativity) since the metric is indefinite. How would one show that the Poincaré group consists of affine maps? This seems really standard but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to prove these kinds of theorems.  One strategy is to argue isometries carry geodesics to geodesics -- i.e. geodesics in the differential-geometric sense are rectifiable curves that locally minimize length.  

Comment: Off-topic question: what are some applications of the Mazur-Ulam theorem?

Comment: I guess what is confusing me is that usually isometries are defined to be smooth maps, but a priori they could just be continuous. Apparently the Myers-Steenrod theorem says that all isometries of Riemannian manifolds are smooth, however this theorem requires the isometry to be surjective. 

Comment: @Boaz: by definition isometries are continuous.  

Comment: Sorry, I meant that usually in the context of Riemannian geometry isometries are defined to be smooth, but a priori an isometry (distance-preserving map) could be continuous but not smooth (in fact there are pathological examples). A sticky point is that an isometry is not necessarily a bijection, and a lot of these theorems are only available for surjective isometries. In particular, I'm not sure that it's obvious for an arbitrary isometry that it takes geodesics to geodesics.

@Tom: I saw the Mazur-Ulam theorem come up in a proof of the Myers-Steenrod theorem . . .

Comment: Now that I think of it, it is not so obvious to me that isometries of pseudo-Riemannian manifolds are continuous. 

Comment: @Boaz what's your definiton of an isometry of a Pseudo-Riemannian manifold? There is no notion of a distance or of arc-length of a continuous curve here.

Comment: I guess I am thinking of a map which preserves "proper time"

Comment: @Boaz: What proper time would that be? you have a continuous map between pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. Proper time is defined for  individual **smooth** timelike curves. Please give a full definition of isometry you want to use.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of the minimal proper time between two points. But maybe this is not a meaningful quantity.

Comment: @Boaz and @Vitali: An isometry of a semi-Riemannian (or pseudo-Riemannian) manifold $(M,g)$ is a diffeomorphism $\phi$ that preserves the metric tensor, i.e., the pull-back of $g$ by $\phi$ coincides with $g$: $\phi^*(g)=g$. I have never seen any other definitions in the literature. Although there is a notion of distance in Lorentzian manifolds (see e.g. the book of O'Neill or the one of Beem, Ehrlich and Easley), there are very few results analogous to the Riemannian case.

Comment: @RyanBudney: in Lorentz signature, geodesics don't minimize length. They are degenerate critical points of the energy integral functional.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's fix notation and define the bilinear form $\eta: \mathbb{R}^4 \times \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ by:

$\eta((x,y,z,t),(x',y',z',t')) = xx'+yy'+zz'- tt'$

Given a map $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ which fixes $0$ and preserves $\eta$ we want to show that $T$ is linear.

Let $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.  The first observation is that for any four vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ such that $\eta(v_i,v_j) = \eta(e_i,e_j)$ for all $i,j$ the linear map sending each $v_i$ to $e_i$ is invertible and preserves $\eta$.

Hence by composing $T$ with a linear invertible $\eta$ preserving map we may assume that $Te_i = e_i$ for $i = 1,2,3,4$.

Now we have for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^4$ that $\eta(v,e_i) = \eta(Tv,Te_i) = \eta(Tv, e_i)$ this implies that $T$ is the identity (since we can get each coordinate of $Tv$).

Comment: What if we only know that $T$ preserves lengths? How do you polarize?

Comment: @Boaz preserves lengths of what? please state your definition of an isometry. One reasonable definition for the Minkowski space is a map that preserves Minkowski norm, i.e. $||f(x)-f(y)||_{3,1}=||x-y||_{3,1}$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^{3,1}$. this polarizes trivially so Pablo's answer is complete with that definition. Another reasonable definition is if you assume that $f$ is smooth and preserves the metric infinitesimally. Then the result is also elementary but judging by your other comment this is not the definition you want. 

Comment: Is the polarization trivial? The usual polarization formula is $4(x,y) = \|x-y\|^2 + \|x+y\|^2$. How do we know that $\|f(x)+f(y)\|=\|x+y\|$?

Comment: yes, the polarization is trivial. we are assuming $f(0)=0$
and $||f(x)-f(y)||^2=||x-y||^2$ for all $x,y$.  Then the  formula $2\langle x, y\rangle=||x|^2+||y||^2-||x-y||^2$ immediately implies that 
 $\langle f(x), f(y)\rangle=\langle x, y\rangle $.

Comment: What is $\nu$? I don't see it defined in either the question or the answer.

Comment: This proves that if you have a map preserving the Minkowski space inner product and the origin, it is linear. But what if we just want a $C^1$ map of Minkowski space to itself, whose differential preserves the Minkowski inner product on each tangent space? This argument doesn't apply, because the inner product is not on points of Minkowski space, but only on their tangent vectors, so that map $T$ doesn't directly apply to tangent vectors, $T'$ does.

Comment: @BenMcKay Assume $T$ fixes the origin.  Since the exponential mapping at the origin is the identity and $T$ preserves geodesics, you deduce $T = T'(0)$.   In general two isometries which coincide at a point up to order one are the same, see the proposition on page 91 of Barrett O'neill's book "Semi-Riemannian geometry".

Answer (score 29):

The following paper shows that if chronological order on $\mathbb R^n$ is defined by cone
(i.e., $x\in \mathbb R^n$ chronologically precedes $y\in \mathbb R^n$ iff $y − x$ belongs to some fixed cone)
then any bijection which preserve the chronological order has to be linear.

- [Alexandrov A.D. Contribution to chronogeometry Canad. J. Math. - 1967.- V.19, N.6. - P.1119-1128.](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1967-102-6)

This statement is much stronger than you need.
After Alexandrov, it was reproved independently 5 times or so.

Answer (score 6):

The following general result is described in the answer I posted on math.stackexchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137139/isometry-without-injection-and-surjection): if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces of equal dimension over an arbitrary field and they are both equipped with nondegenerate bilinear forms $B_1$ and $B_2$, then a function $\sigma \colon V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ such that $B_1(v,w) = B_2(\sigma(v),\sigma(w))$ for all $v$ and $w$ in $V_1$ must be an isomorphism of vector spaces (linear, injective, and surjective). The proof does not use non-degeneracy of $B_2$ on $V_2$, so that property  actually follows from non-degeneracy of $B_1$ on $V_1$.

In the particular case you ask about, where $V_1 = V_2$ and $B_1 = B_2$, the result says: for a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over an arbitrary field and a nondegenerate bilinear form $B$ on $V$, a function $\sigma \colon V \rightarrow V$ for which $B(v,w) = B(\sigma(v),\sigma(w))$ for all $v$ and $w$ in $V$ must be  linear, injective, and surjective.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked out the details, so I might have this all wrong, but couldn't you proceed as follows:

1. Prove that an isometry is differentiable.
2. Prove that an isometry is an infinitesimal isometry. In other words, the pull back of the   metric tensor is equal to the metric tensor.
3. Prove that the composition of any linear co-ordinate function with the infinitesimal isometry has vanishing Hessian (this requires both metrics be flat) and therefore is also a linear co-ordinate function.
4. Conclude that the map is linear, since it maps linear co-ordinate functions to linear co-ordinate functions.

It seems to me that the proof that an isometry is linear should be very similar to the proof that any flat metric is locally isometric to the standard one.